# Loading video using QMediaPlayer and UNC paths

Tags: qt, qt5, multimedia, unc, qmediaplayer

I'm trying to load a video from a network using UNC paths thanks to Qt 5.5 [QMediaPlayer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html).
The code snippet is the following one:

```
projectDirectory = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory (this,
                                                      tr ("Choose project folder (sensor + video data"),
                                                      QDir::homePath(), QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly);

QDir dir(projectDirectory);
QStringList test = dir.entryList();
qDebug () << projectDirectory << "contains:" << endl << test;
mediaPlayer.setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(projectDirectory+"/video.mov"));
```

The code snippet works for a local file but doesn't work when the path begins with `//`.

Example output:

```
"//m4800/Partage/111" contains: 
(".", "..", "HandBrake.txt", "sensors.csv", "video.mov")
DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource: Unresolved error code 80004005
```

Note that I am able to read the `sensors.csv` text file and that `video.mov` has the same permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
mediaPlayer.setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(projectDirectory+"/video.mov"));
```

remove ::fromLocalFile and try

```
mediaPlayer.setMedia(QUrl(projectDirectory+"/video.mov"));
```

This seems to solve the problem. In the codebase I am working on, we have added a check for "//" at the start of the raw path before creating the URL to check it is a UNC path and still use the fromLocalFile if it is not.

Comment: Works perfectly with Qt 5.5.0 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

The DirectShow library does not appear to correctly support UNC paths.

You either have to copy the file to a local temp folder or load the file into a QByteArray and stream from there.

Neither is a great solution and Microsoft depreciated DirectShow in favour of Media Foundation (which has limited playback support at this time).