# Convert Windows UNC path to QUrl for Mac

Tags: windows, macos, pyqt5, unc, qurl

Background: I've got a database where paths to video files are stored as Windows UNC path strings, for example "\\11.22.33.44\path\movie.mp4". (The Windows format is a legacy thing and I can't fundamentally change how these are stored).

I'm now working on a Python media player using PyQt5's QMediaPlayer. On Windows, it's working fine, and:

```
self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(str(fileName))))
```

opens up the movie file in the player.

However there's a requirement to make this work on Mac as well, and I'm hitting problems getting the Windows UNC path into a QUrl format that works on Mac. I've tried various `os.path` and `pathlib` examples online, but none of them seem to create a valid path that `QUrl.fromLocalFile` will work with. I'm always hitting `Error: Failed to load media`. I'm getting results like "/11.22.33.44/file/movie.mp4" where there's both a backslash and a foreslash at the start, things like that.

I should point out that yes these are network paths, being sent to a method called 'fromLocalFile', but the documentation for QUrl does state that it will work with network paths: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#fromLocalFile- so I don't think that should be the issue?

Can somebody please explain to me the proper way to make this work? I assume Pathlib should be able to use this and I'm just approaching it the wrong way.

(This question is NOT a duplicate of [Loading video using QMediaPlayer and UNC paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32739198/loading-video-using-qmediaplayer-and-unc-paths) because my code IS working on Windows and I'm having a different problem with Mac-friendly paths.)

Comment: I don't understand why the user would be using a UNC path under macOS?  Wouldn't the remote server be mounted on the filesystem?

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks for the question. In the current set-up, it can't be assumed that server connection has already been made (there are multiple servers involved and the software users won't necessarily have connected to all of them). And even if mounting could be assumed, I currently don't know how I would translate a UNC to the equivalent 'Volumes' path.

Comment: Well that's my point; there won't be a UNC under anything but Windows.  All O/S's have their own way to specify remote server paths etc.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm unused to Macs and how their mounting works. If I understand you correctly, you're saying that there will be so simple path solution, and a more advanced solution involving creating mount points will be required?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure to be honest.  As ekhumoro's answer shows, it might use an `smb://` URL scheme instead.  However I reckon his platform-specific code should be compile time (i.e. `#ifdef`s) and not runtime.

Comment: @trojanfoe This is Python, so there is no compile time. And my code is not platform-specific.

Comment: @ekhumoro Makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt whether there's a completely reliable and portable way to do this for an arbitrary network path. However, assuming your Windows UNC paths are always in the same format, something like this should work:

```
import platform
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

def make_url(unc):
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(unc)
    else:
        url = QUrl(unc.replace('\\', '/'))
        if platform.system() == 'Darwin':
            url.setScheme('smb')
    return url

print(make_url(r'\\11.22.33.44\path\movie.mp4'))
```

Or if that doesn't work, try:

```
def make_url(unc):
    if platform.system() != 'Windows':
        unc = unc.replace('\\', '/')
    return QUrl.fromLocalFile(unc)
```

(NB: I am on Linux, so I have no way of testing this).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @ekhumoro. This feels like progress, but unfortunately it hasn't proven to be a full fix. The QUrl output is now represented as `smb://11.22.33.44/path/movie.mp4`, which looks better than before to me, but the QMediaPlayer still says `Failed to load media`. However if I browse to the MP4 using a QFileDialog, the fileName returned is represented as a QUrl `file:///11.22.33.44/path/movie.mp4` and that's working, but the samba path is not. :-(

Comment: @TwentyPenguins Okay, on the basis that a `file:` url is working for you, I have added a simpler solution.

Comment: Unfortunately my previous comment was incorrect, my mistake. `file:///11.22.33.44/path/` paths are _not_ working, but `file:///Volumes/path/` (mounted) paths, manually selected, _are_ working. So while your code successfully forms the correct path (thank you for that), unfortunately I still have the problem of not being able to assume a drive is mounted, or being able to translate an IP-based UNC to a Volumes mount path.

Comment: @TwentyPenguins So now your question has changed quite radically. This is why Qt and Python don't provide this sort of functionality out of the box. You will have to find a way to obtain the correct mount-point from the ip address programmatically. As it stands, I don't think your question is really answerable. Or at least, my answer is about as far as you can get in terms of simple path/url manipulations.

Comment: Thank you. You are of course correct, the paths are being formed correctly and the issue is a different one regarding mount points and feeding Samba shares to QMediaPlayer on a Mac. I will investigate further and see if I can form a sensible new question.